# How can I use the same transaction across steps in Camel?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, apache-camel

In [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/dsl.html), is it possible to use the same transaction on different steps of the same route? Obviously, I can pass it as an attribute in the message; but I'm looking for something less intrusive, like an annotation and maybe an interceptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can, and [the Fuse documentation](http://fusesource.com/docs/router/2.2/transactions/index.html) explains how to do it.